# Cannot resolve method setSupportActionBar(androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar)

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I'm using androidx and i'm trying to set a toolbar in my Mainactivity so that I can add menu items.

I have searched everywhere but can't seem to get a solution
tried `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'`

Mainactivity.class

`import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            style="@style/HeaderBar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="HeaderBar">

    <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```

Comment: what is parent class of your `Mainactivity`?

Comment: Mainactivity extends FragmentActivity

Answer (score 12):

The issue must come from the fact that the `Toolbar` you are referencing in your `MainActivity` class is the `Toolbar` widget from (`android.widget`) as shown in the image below:

[image]Instead of the Toolbar from the (`androidx.appcompact.widget`) as shown in the image below:

[image]

So when typing "Toolbar" in the `MainActivity` class, make sure to slow down and check that the `Toolbar` you're referencing is the (`androidx.appcompat.widget`) one.

Comment: Both your links returns 404

Comment: Sorry about that, Just fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

I met the same problem. I use in Kotlin.

**integrate with "com.google.android.material.material:1.1.0-alpha06"**

fragment.xml

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
   android:id="@+id/toolbar"
   ...
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

Fragment

```
activity?.setActionBar(toolbar)
```

the error: 
setActionBar(required: android.widget.Toolbar),but I can not find setSupportActionBar in Kotlin

**If I change the widget**

```
<android.widget.Toolbar>
       android:id="@+id/toolbar"
       ...
</android.widget.Toolbar>
```

Fragment: ok

```
activity?.setActionBar(toolbar)
```

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find much in the documentation regarding this, it worked for me by:

1. In your layout and activity instead of using androidx, use appcompat toolbar widget.
2. Use `setActionBar()` instead of `setSupportActionBar()` in your activity's `onCreate()` method
3. Set NoActionBar theme in AndroidManifest for your activity to avoid interference with your custom toolbar.

In your layout.xml

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        //your views here

    </Toolbar>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

In Activity

```
android.widget.Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setActionBar(toolbar);
```

In AndroidManifest.xml where your activity is declared

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
```

Answer (score 1):

I also have run to this problem when created Google Maps Activity which extend `FragmentActivity (androidx.appcompat.app.FragmentActivity)`. To solve this problem, 
make sure your activity extends `AppCompatActivity (androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity)`.

Also check your `gradle.properties` and make sure `android.useAndroidX=true` and `android.enableJetifier=true` are listed there.